# nginx seems to use wrong php service

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, curl, php.ini

i wanted to increase my max. upload file size and install cURL to php5-fpm today. I have installed a LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 14.04. But the changes doesn't take any effect after reloading/restarting php5-fpm and nginx..

Now i have removed everything with php from the server to test if nginx is using these services but it's still running.. On my nginx i use following configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I don#t know what to do now no changes take any effect.. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: "But the changes doesn't take any effect" which one? And how exactly have you tested it?

Comment: Why did you install an entire LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) when all you needed was PHP? There are multiple php.ini files lying around on many systems, which one did you change. What was it before, and what is it now. You really need to give more information if you want useful help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the maximum upload file size, than you have to do the following:

```
vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Change the values in php.ini to something like you can see below (for example 32 Megabytes):

```
...
post_max_size = 32M
...
upload_max_filesize = 32M
...
```

To reload your new PHP configuration you have to restart the php5-fpm daemon:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

**Hint:** For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it doesn't work to restart the service via /etc/init.d/php5-fpm.